# Can SQL queries be combined?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have to go into a table to retrieve a parameter, then go back into the same table to retrieve data based on the parameter.

```
<cfquery name = "selnm" datasource = "Moxart">
 select SelName from AuxXref 
 where Fieldname = <cfqueryparam value = "#orig#">
</cfquery>

<cfset selname = selnm.SelName>

<cfquery name = "fld" datasource = "Moxart">
select Fieldname, DBname from AuxXref 
where SelName = <cfqueryparam value = "#selname#">
</cfquery>
```

Can this be done in a single query?

Comment: Both of these queries select data from the same table. Why can't you select Fieldname/DBname directly where fieldname and selname both equal #orig#?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should also be specifying a cfsqltype, to take full advantage of cfqueryparam. Otherwise, it defaults to `cf_sql_char` which is not always desirable.

Comment: @BKK SelName is never = #orig#. Please see my answer to Scott below.

Comment: @Leigh as usual you are improving my code.  Could you tell my how to specify the cfsqltype?  Do I just set it before the query, or is it part of the cfquery line?

Comment: It's an attribute on [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam).

Comment: To answer your question, yes, you can put more than one SQL statement in CFQuery tags. However, ColdFusion does not know how to deal with more than one recordset returned. For example, you can insert and select in the same cfquery group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one query like so:

```
<cfquery name = "fld" datasource = "Moxart">
   select Fieldname, DBname, SelName from AuxXref 
   where SelName = <cfqueryparam value = "#orig#">
   AND FieldName = <cfqueryparam value = "#orig#"> 
</cfquery>
```

Comment: For one SelName there are numerous Fieldnames, many of which will not equal #orig#. I've got to find the SelName for this one particular Fieldname, and then find all the other Fieldnames that have the same SelName.

Comment: It sounds like you expected logic is different from you orginal question. Your comment makes me think you are trying to do an OR operation

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might satisfy your requirements.

```
select fieldname, DBname
from AuxXref
where selname in 
(select distinct selname
 from auxXref
 where fieldname = <cfqueryparam value = "#orig#">
)
and fieldname <> <cfqueryparam value = "#orig#">
```

If the subquery returns more than one row, and you only want one, then you'll have to specify which one you want.

Comment: The DISTINCT and final line are probably redundant, but otherwise this matches with what I'm reading the OP was going for.

Comment: @PeterBoughton yes this is what I am going for.  I didn't know how to form the subquery.  The distinct makes me a bit nervous because there is only one Selname involved, but numerous Fieldnames, and I'm not sure how distinct works in that situation.  The subquery may well return more than one row, and that is what I want if there is more that one Fieldname matching that Selname.

Comment: For what it's worth, I added the distinct keyword because I believe it will make the query run faster.